# Word to PDF conversion: Fonts look crisp at 150% zoom but fuzzy at the desired 100% zoom

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, conversion, adobe-acrobat

Is there a way to force the PDF to optimize text rendering for a zoom factor of 100%?

I've written an IT Textbook (on Advanced Excel) in MS Word and I'm trying to create a crisp PDF. I know that InDesign would be a better tool for this, but I don't have it, and don't know how to use it yet. I'm likely going to learn in the next few months, but meanwhile I'm stuck with what I've got.

In my Word-To-PDF am striking a few issues. I'd post screenshots, but I don't have enough reputation points on SuperUser (although strangely I do have enough rep to post on the StackOverflow site, and it puzzles me that I can't transfer that kudos from there to here).
Here's my issue:

- The screenshots (mostly) look crisp at a zoom setting of 100% in
  Adobe Acrobat or Adobe reader,  but the text looks a little fuzzy
- The Text Looks crisp at a zoom setting of 121.4% (which is what came
  up automatically when I held the Ctrl key down and turned the scroll
  wheel on my mouse to increase the zoom factor), but this makes the
  images fuzzy, as they've been zoomed beyond their native 96 DPI
  resolution.

So question is this: Is there a way to force the PDF to optimize text rendering for a zoom factor of 100%?

Note that I had to change the Resolution setting in Adobe from the default of 110 to my 'system setting' of 96 in order to get those images to appear crisp under the 100% Zoom scenario. Without this change, it seems Adobe was scaling the images up by 110/96 = ~15% which meant the images didn't look crisp at 100%. In fact, at 100% zoom under this setting they look as fuzzy as they did under 121.4% zoom scenario under the old setting.

I don't really understand why, but no doubt it's tied up with the settings I used in Snagit to take the original screenshots and/or the resolution of my display or printer.

Does anyone know how I can solve this conundrum?

Comment: Are you suing embedded fonts? If you use default Windows fonts, they should be scalable.

Comment: Just to understand the issue correctly, you are talking about the crispness of the text in the screenshots you place in your document? Also, how exactly are you creating the PDFs out of Word?

Comment: Hi Max. No, I'm not talking about screenshots but crispness of the actual body text itself. And I've tried using both Word's inbuilt 'Export to PDF' tool as well as Adobe Acrobat and get the same issue with both.

Comment: Hu DrMaush. I'm not sure. Will check what I did. Newbie in training!

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. As far as I know, fonts are embedded. For a small sample file, in Document Properties>Fonts it shows I have three fonts:
Calibri-light (Embedded Subset) Type: TrueType Encoding: Ansi 
Calibri-light (Embedded Subset) Type: CID Encoding: Identity-H
Calibri-lightItalic (Embedded Subset) Type: CID Encoding: Identity-H